# Alternating Series and Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The question is: Approximate the value of the series within an error of at most $10^{-4}$.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{(n+79)(n+73)} $$

According to

$$|S_N - S| ≤ a_{N+1}$$

what is the smallest value of $N$ that approximates $S$ to within an error of at most $10^{-4}$?

I have tried the following to get $N$:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{(n+79)(n+73)}$$

$$\frac{1}{(n+79)(n+73)} < \frac{1}{10000}$$

$N=25$

How do I solve for $S$?

Comment: You got an inequality $\frac{1}{(n+79)(n+73)}<10^{-4}$. Solve for $n$. Take, say the minimum of the solutions for $n$ (among the positive integers) and sum that many terms from the series.

Comment: You could split the term into partial fractions, and compute the sums for the separate fractions as (differences of) harmonic numbers. But it is probably just easier to ask your tame CAS, which will helpfully answer 20741307670754148683540176337/138604552554242850002258263732800 (1.4964376918743016e-4). Courtesy of [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by vonbrand, the series can be split by using partial fraction decomposition. Rewrite
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{(n+79)(n+73)}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{6}\left(\frac{1}{n+73}-\frac{1}{n+79}\right).
\end{align}
$$
This is [a telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and the fraction terms will cancel out for $n>6$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{(n+79)(n+73)}&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{n+73}-\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{n+79}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^6 \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{n+73}.\\
\end{align}
$$
Since the series is only left $6$ terms, its summation value will easy be obtained by pocket calculator.

---

$$\large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$